# How to check an get without a value?

Tags: php, get

I am currently working on a simple project but I don't wanna use long nasty url's; `"cpanel/list?get=types"`, instead of that I wanna use `"cpanel/list?types"`.

I've tried it by checking if it exists etc. but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `isset()` function.

Comment: Thanks got it, `if (isset($_GET['muscles']))
            echo "muscles";`

Comment: I didn't see the `get=...` part, hence deleted my answer. Glad it solved your problem. :)

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `isset`

```
if(isset($_GET['types'])){
    // do soemthing
}else{
    // do something else
}
```

other wise..

```
$type=$_GET['type'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using long query of url you can use sef link(sef url), i suggest you to search this topic.